# importing XML into MySQL with PHP only getting first child data

Tags: php, mysql, xml

After much trial and error, I finally have my PHP code importing XML data into MySQL. The only problem, its only getting data from the first child node.

My XML data is structured as such;

```
<Machine>
    <Stem>
        <Log>
            <ProductKey>1713</ProductKey>
            <LogVolume logVolumeCategory="m3sub" logMeasurementCategory="Machine">0.5682</LogVolume>
            <LogMeasurement logMeasurementCategory="Machine">
                <LogLength>551</LogLength>
            </LogMeasurement>
         </Log>
        <Log>
            <ProductKey>1713</ProductKey>
            <LogVolume logVolumeCategory="m3sub" logMeasurementCategory="Machine">0.5682</LogVolume>
            <LogMeasurement logMeasurementCategory="Machine">
                <LogLength>551</LogLength>
            </LogMeasurement>
         </Log>
        <Log>
            <ProductKey>1713</ProductKey>
            <LogVolume logVolumeCategory="m3sub" logMeasurementCategory="Machine">0.5682</LogVolume>
            <LogMeasurement logMeasurementCategory="Machine">
                <LogLength>551</LogLength>
            </LogMeasurement>
         </Log>
    </Stem>
    <Stem>
        <Log>
            <ProductKey>1713</ProductKey>
            <LogVolume logVolumeCategory="m3sub" logMeasurementCategory="Machine">0.5682</LogVolume>
            <LogMeasurement logMeasurementCategory="Machine">
                <LogLength>551</LogLength>
            </LogMeasurement>
         </Log>
        <Log>
            <ProductKey>1713</ProductKey>
            <LogVolume logVolumeCategory="m3sub" logMeasurementCategory="Machine">0.5682</LogVolume>
            <LogMeasurement logMeasurementCategory="Machine">
                <LogLength>551</LogLength>
            </LogMeasurement>
         </Log>
        <Log>
            <ProductKey>1713</ProductKey>
            <LogVolume logVolumeCategory="m3sub" logMeasurementCategory="Machine">0.5682</LogVolume>
            <LogMeasurement logMeasurementCategory="Machine">
                <LogLength>551</LogLength>
            </LogMeasurement>
         </Log>
    </Stem>
</Machine>
```

PHP;

```
foreach($data->Stem as $Stem)
    {
        $statement->execute(
            array(
            ':productkey'    => $Stem->SingleTreeProcessedStem->Log->ProductKey,
            ':logvolume'     => $Stem->SingleTreeProcessedStem->Log->LogVolume[1],
            ':loglength'     => $Stem->SingleTreeProcessedStem->Log->LogMeasurement->LogLength
            )
        );

    }
```

At the moment, this is looping through all **Stem** tags and getting the information for the first **Log** tag. 
I need it to get information from ALL log tags. 
I have tried to rewrite my foreach statement, however I am still new to this so I'm hoping someone might be able to tell me where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one more `foreach` loop:

```
foreach($data->Stem as $Stem)
{
    foreach($Stem->Log as $Log) {
        $statement->execute(
            array(
                ':productkey'    => $Stem->SingleTreeProcessedStem->Log->ProductKey,
                ':logvolume'     => $Stem->SingleTreeProcessedStem->Log->LogVolume[1],
                ':loglength'     => $Stem->SingleTreeProcessedStem->Log->LogMeasurement->LogLength
            )
        );
    }
}
```